# Most efficient way to print differences of two arrays?

Tags: collections, compare, complexity-theory, assert

Recently, a colleague of mine asked me how he could test the equalness of two arrays. He had two sources of `Address` and wanted to assert that both sources contained exactly the same elements, although order didn't matter.
Both using `Array` or like `List` in Java, or `IList` would be okay, but since there could be two equal `Address` objects, things like `Set`s can't be used.

In most programming languages, a `List` already has an `equals` method doing the comparison (assuming that the collection was ordered before doing it), but there is no information about the actual differences; only that there are some, or none.

The output should inform about elements that are in one collection but not in the other, and vice-versa.

An obvious approach would be to iterate through one of the collections (if one of them is), and just call `contains(element)` on the other one, and doing it the the other way around afterwards. Assuming a complexity of `O(n)` for `contains`, that would result in `O(2n²)`, if I'm correct.

Is there a more efficient way for getting the information "A1 and A2 isn't in List1, A3 and A4 isn't in List2"? Are there data structures better suited for doing this job than lists? Is it worth it to sort the collections before and using a custom, binary search contains?

Comment: The problem you are describing seems to fit using sets. Don't discard them as they can be pretty efficient and easy to use sometimes. I've answered with a few more details

Comment: @Davide sorting an array is orders of magnitudes faster than inserting and iterating over sets - just to keep in mind

Comment: @BeyelerStudios You don't have to sort and iterate over sets to find their differences...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I'm sorry, I didn't mean to say "sort a set" which is just stupid as sets don't have a notion of order

Comment: @Davide how do you imagine a *set* to be implemented when not as a) a hash table (bad spacial locality for lookups) or b) sorted array or list (i.e. a tree/heap)? building a set is equal to sorting.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I don't have to imagine it. Bloom already did that in 1970. Bloom filters are a implementation of sets which allows you to add to sets and check if an element exists all in constant time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Comment: @Davide You're comparing apples and oranges: probabilistic approaches are just that - probabilistic. if you care about "is this element in my set" you cannot use bloom filters - I need to see an implementation which corrects for this and beat array sorting to believe it

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Since this is getting off-topic I'll just say you are right. Sets are inefficient and useless because you can just sort an array, which is always faster and has great spacial locality

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is using set difference

In pseudo-python

```
addr1 = set(originalAddr1)
addr2 = set(originalAddr2)
in1notin2 = addr1 - addr2
in2notin1 = addr2 - addr1
allDifferences = in1notin2 + in2notin1
```

From [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) you can see that set difference is `O(len(set))` and union is `O(len(set1) + len(set2))` giving you a linear time solution with this python specific `set` implementation, instead of quadratic as you suggest.

I believe other popular languages tend to implement these type of data structures pretty much the same way, but can't really be sure about this.

Comment: what is the cost of building the sets ?

Comment: But `set` wouldn't be able to handle duplicates? Having Collection1: `E1 E1` and Collection2: `E1` - output should be like `E1 is missing in second collection`

Comment: @stuXnet oh, if that's really what you want, then sets are most definitely off the table. Even though `E1 is missing in second collection` is clearly misleading as `E1` is in fact in the second collection...

Comment: You're right, a wording like `found a E1 that isn't in the second collection` or something like that would be more clear, but that doesn't have to change the algorithm :)

Comment: @AndréR. I don't know and I can't find the answer, but my best guess would be that a conversion from list to set would be `O(n)`, but it's just intuition.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it worth to sort the collection [...]?

Compare the naive approach `O(n²)` to sorting two lists in `O(n logn)` and then comparing them in `O(n)` - or sorting one list in `O(n logn)` and iterating over the other in `O(n)`